# Missing tags, will someone with a reputation >= 300 create tags for pyRenamer and Krename

Tags: support, status-declined, tags

In question regarding batch rename, the tags pyRenamer and Krename don't exists (and should). I don't have the need rep of 300+ to create them. Will someone here - with the capacity to create tags do so - please & thank you.

Comment: Link to the question please?

Comment: If I can remember or get them.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/47587/renaming-multiple-files-by-adding-a-string-to-the-beginning/52897#52897 & http://askubuntu.com/questions/44736/how-to-bulk-rename-files-after-modification-date

Answer (score 4):

May I ask why you need these two tags created?  Not every program in the repositories requires a tag, and tags should only be created  when they are **absolutely** needed.  Otherwise, if they're sparsely used, they tend to get removed or merged with other tags.

***EDIT***
A google search of the site for `pyRenamer` only returns it being mentioned as a solution for mass renaming.  Same for `Krename`.  There is no need for a tag for a program that is mentioned as a solution - only for a tag in which there are at least a few questions pertaining to the need for support with a program (i.e. "pyRenamer won't run, how can I fix this?"), to which this does not apply.

***EDIT2***
We have decided that the tags for the specific programs themselves is now unnecessary.  Per the comments to this answer, it has now come down to deciding on whether to leave the [rename](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/rename) tag as is or whether to split them: [general-rename](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/general-rename) and [mass-rename](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mass-rename).  My opinion on this is as follows:  For the given use cases as specified in teh question's comments showing two questions pertaining to mass renaming, the [rename](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/rename) tag is sufficient for the purpose: "rename" covers manual renaming and technically mass renaming as both are renaming of files.  At this point, we would like community involvement in this question, including moderator opinions.

Comment: There were several questions on batch renaming, in which the rename tag was not sufficient. In these questions, Krename and pyRenamer were the recommends. I wanted to edit and add a batch rename tag - but can't do to my rep limitations. Tags referring to batch renaming would be helpful. So if not, Krename or pyRename - specific to the packages, then a general rename (F2) and rename-batch.

Comment: I'd be for a mass-rename or batch-rename tag.  But again, we should never create a tag for just a package or program unless its needed for support of those programs.  Since it is *not* for those programs a more generic tag is needed, such as batch-rename.  And we can't change currently-existing tags, so you're SOL on changing rename to rename-f2 (which makes no sense anyways to have).

Comment: Further, the rename tag is technically sufficient for those questions - it does pertain to renaming files, whether with the F2 button, using the CLI (`mv name newname`), and mass-renaming.  As such, I believe we should have moderators weigh in on this prior to any action.

Comment: I think the current tag is sufficient as there are only 10 rename questions splitting it now will just make meta-tags

Comment: I agree with @Marco on this.  There's really no solid justification for splitting [tag:rename] items into meta-tags.